# Which BouncyCastle API-supported Encryption algorithm is fastest for short string encryption in C# .NET and pretty safe?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, encryption, bouncycastle

I tried to search stackoverflow for an answer to this particular question but couldn't find a good answer.

The BouncyCastle API offers a ton of different encryption algorithms for .NET. In this case I have to select an encryption algorithm for the following use case:

1. Encrypting several thousand short strings for storage in an unencrypted file, typical length 10-30 characters.
2. Encryption needs to be only moderately secure, all strings will be encrypted with the same key but a different initialization vector. Things like authorization (like in AES-GCM) are not needed.

Which encryption algorithm is both fastest and straightforward to apply for encrypting and decrypting such a set of several thousand small strings? I will store the encrypted data of each string as BASE64 in the file.

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Fastest on what hardware? on what software? What is the purpose of encrypting 'several thousand' strings individually and then storing in ONE unstructured file? I imagine the biggest bottleneck you will have is IO (reading/writing the same unstructured file)

Comment: .NET Framework 4.x based Office VSTO solution. We want the software to be speedy on a 7-year old Haswell laptop still (in companies there are a lot of older notebooks around). File I/O is not the problem, they way we write the files these thousands of strings are written to the file in just a few milliseconds. If we can encrypt and decrypt 5000 small strings (10-30 characters) in under 5 milliseconds on a Core i5-4250u based notebook that is good enough performance for our purposes won't noticeably slow down the user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That processor still has AES-NI, so using that through the `AES.Create` seems most logical. A higher end solution would be to create CTR mode out of ECB (and cache the key streams).

Otherwise you are looking for a fast stream cipher in software. You could check if Salsa20 is working for you. Unfortunately that's the only eStream-compatible cipher that I can find in Bouncy Castle for C#.

Note that you may want to look into multi-threading and I would certainly check if it is possible to use sequential nonce when using a stream cipher, as generating a 128 bit random value for each encryption seems wasteful.

Comment: Thank you Maarten I will check out Salsa20 as well. 

I tested System.Security.Cryptography library with 128 BITS AES CBC and for thousands of small strings it was slow, I did not use an accurate measurement tool but this is the user experience (and from some measurements with the .NET stopwatch).

Yes multithreading would be possible in our scenario (there is other processing that could be parallel as it is non-dependent).

A sequential nonce is also fine we are not looking for more than moderate security.

Comment: A sequential nonce is fully secure, but a repeated nonce is catastrophic for stream / counter mode encryption, so beware, especially if you are going to use multiple threads.

Comment: Good to know intuitively I'd think a sequential one wouldn't be really safe but of course behind encryption algorithms there is some sophisticated mathematics :).

Comment: Well in the case of repeated nonce you just require XOR and a counter to get the XOR of the two plaintext values. I don't know what you call "sophisticated mathematics", but breaking a multi-time-pad is usually the first or second practice assignment in crypto courses.

Comment: I am just a 'consumer' of the encryption libraries so I have very little understanding of how they work, but good to know and yes should learn more about the subject :).

Comment: I did some more research and it seems that Salsa20 is plenty fast in *optimized* implementations. It also has a fast initial key setup (which is not that surprising if you understand the implementation details), which means that it should be very suitable for smaller strings. I could find Sosemanuk and Rabbit as other possible (slightly faster) ciphers, but you'd have to get another library for those. Other than that I only think XTEA might be of interest - at least that one is included. I could not find a 64 bit optimized stream cipher, strangely enough.

Comment: Thank you so much Maarten I will start with Salsa20 and see what performance I can get from it. I will try the Salsa20 implementation in BouncyCastle first to see how much performance I can get from their (hopefully adequately optimized) implementation.